# Textarea placeholder not working on iphone phonegap

Tags: iphone, css, html, cordova

I am working on phonegap with iphone and having problem with textarea placeholder.

Main problem is: I set the placeholder to text area but when page loads it doesn't show me placeholder text bun when I click on the blank text inside textarea placeholder will be shown.

I surf a lot about it and even use many jQuery but problem is still on.

**EDIT**

My Html is

```
<textarea id="statusText" class="comments_fontsize" placeholder="Update your status"> </textarea>
```

Comment: please try to post your code..

Comment: @Sudha : I am working on phonegap with ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between both  tags. The browser reads is as if there was data inside of it (a space in this case).